# How to set CRS for a DXF file and prevent any warning on QGIS using pyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, ogr

I am trying to import dxf file with no warnings or popup from Spatial Reference Selector. However, even after modifying QGIS Spatial Reference Selector setting, I still get a qgisMessagebar warning. 
This is what I have done so far.

```
    dxf_file = 'D:/mydxf.dxf'
    dxf_file_url = dxf_file + '|layername=entities|geometrytype=Point'
    #setting to suppress the popup
    s = QSettings()
    oldValidation = str(s.value( "/Projections/defaultBehaviour", "useGlobal" ))
    s.setValue( "/Projections/defaultBehaviour", "useGlobal" )
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(dxf_file_url, 'layer_name', 'ogr')
    s.setValue( "/Projections/defaultBehaviour", oldValidation )
```

So what I want to achieve is, either insert projection to the dxf file before it goes into QgsVectorLayer or to hide the QgsMessagebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restart QGIS in order for the change for QSettings to take effect. What your code is doing is changing these settings:

[image: CRS Settings]

Where:

```
# Prompt for CRS = "prompt"
# Use project CRS = "useProject"
# Use a default CRS = "useGlobal"

from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
QSettings().setValue("/Projections/defaultBehaviour", "useGlobal")
```

When you restart QGIS, it should no longer prompt you for the CRS.

---

I don't think it's possible to define a CRS for a layer **before** using `QgsVectorLayer` as you would be setting a CRS for a string path (which brings up an error).

**EDIT**:

Once you set up the CRS settings, you can use the following to load the layer without the `QgsMessageBar` appearing:

```
dxf_file = 'D:/mydxf.dxf'
dxf_file_url = dxf_file + '|layername=entities|geometrytype=Point'
layer = QgsVectorLayer(dxf_file_url, 'layer_name', 'ogr')
qgis.utils.iface.messageBar().clearWidgets()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have done that already and it has stopped the popup. However, it is still showing warning under qgsMessagebar. How could I get rid of it the same way?

Comment: @andex - Ah, I see. Not sure yet on how to 'disable' the `QgsMessageBar`, hopefully others can advise on this =)

Comment: @andex - Edited the post buddy, Essentially, you can just add `qgis.utils.iface.messageBar().clearWidgets()` to the end of your code to remove the warning message.

Comment: @andex - Awesome buddy, glad it worked =)